# .Net - copy a list that uses class 'A' to a new list that uses class 'B' which inherits from class 'A' and adds new items\variables

Tags: c#, .net, list, class

I have a list that is created as follows. It uses third party wrapper that manages downloading xml information from a computer game:-

```
List<EveAI.Live.Asset> lst_eveai_characterabc_assets = eve_api.GetCharacterAssets();
```

The class definition for Asset is:-

```
namespace EveAI.Live
{
  [TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
  public class Asset
  {
    public Asset();

    public ContainerType Container { get; set; }
    public List<Asset> Contents { get; set; }
    public double ContentsVolume { get; }
    public bool IsSingleton { get; set; }
    public long ItemID { get; set; }
    [Obsolete("Will be removed in a future version, use LocationStation or      
    LocationSolarsystem or LocationConquerableStation instead")]
    public Station Location { get; set; }
    public ConquerableStation LocationConquerableStation { get; set; }
    public int LocationID { get; set; }
    public SolarSystem LocationSolarsystem { get; set; }
    public Station LocationStation { get; set; }
    public long Quantity { get; set; }
    public int RawQuantity { get; set; }
    public ProductType Type { get; set; }
    public int TypeID { get; set; }

    public override string ToString();
  }
}
```

I want to copy list lst_eveai_characterabc_assets to a new list that uses class AssetUniverseIDs - that inherits class EveAI.Live.Asset Something Like:-

```
public class AssetUniverseIDs : EveAI.Live.Asset
{
  public Int32 stationID {get;set;}
  public Int32 stationTypeID { get; set; }
  public Int32 corporationID { get; set; }
  public Int32 solarSystemID { get; set; }
  public string solarSystemName { get; set; }
  public double security { get; set; }
  public string securityClass { get; set; }
  public Int32 constellationID { get; set; }
  public Int32 regionID { get; set; }
  public string regionName { get; set; }
  public string stationName { get; set; }
}
```

But so far I am unable to copy lst_eveai_characterabc_assets to a new list that uses class AssetUniverseIDs that inherits class Assets.  How could I achieve this please.

Comment: Would you mind making much smaller sample by removing unnecessary members and try changing names to follow default C# convention?

Comment: This seems like you are building a bot for the game Eve, which I believe would be against their terms of service.

Comment: so u need all instance of class from "lst_eveai_characterabc_assets" that inherits AssetUniverseIDs?

Comment: Re Malcolm - The company that manages EVE - CCP has provided an extensive API that allows programmers to download xml information about characters.  The general rule is that its ok to get and manage character data so long as it does not give an unfair over other players.  For what I am doing getting my in game character asset data is ok.  I am using EveAI wrapper which manages the lower level downloading of xml data and the cache timing of it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14486945/922198

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet here may be a copy constructor:

```
public AssetUniverseIDs(EveAI.Live.Assett original)
{
     this.Container = original.Container;
     this.Contents = original.Contents;
     // ...
}
```

Then you can build a list of AssetUniverseIDs from a list of Assets like this:

```
List<AssetUniverseIDs> newList = 
    lst_eveai_characterabc_assets.Select(a => new AssetUniverseIDs(a)).ToList();
```

Is there a particular reason you want `AssetUniverseIDs` to inherit from `Asset`?  Perhaps it would be sufficient to just have a class with an `Asset` as one of its properties?

Comment: There is a lot of nested data that List<EveAI.Live.Asset> lst_eveai_characterabc_assets = eve_api.GetCharacterAssets(); gets. A lot of which I don't really need.  So I could for loop through all of lst_eveai_characterabc_assets and cherry pick what I only need to a list that uses class AssetUniverseIDs which inherits from class EveAI.Live.Asset with some but not all nested lists that lst_eveai_characterabc_assets has.